# install JAR from remote repo (clojar)

Tags: maven, jar, clojure

I want to download and install [this](https://clojars.org/clj-http/versions/0.4.1) Clojure library but cannot for the life of me figure it out. I researched Maven, but couldn't get it to find the repo. How can I easily install a Clojure library onto my machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

download https://clojars.org/repo/clj-http/clj-http/0.4.1/clj-http-0.4.1.jar

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=clj-http -DartifactId=clj-http -Dversion=0.4.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=clj-http-0.4.1.jar
```

Comment: This worked, but I have no idea what I did. Could you offer a sentence of explanation?

Comment: install 3rd party jars to local repository, please check out maven docs: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 10):

You could add the repository containing this jar to your pom or settings file and specify the relevant jar as a dependency.

```html
<repository>
  <id>clojars.org</id>
  <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
</repository>
...
<dependency>
   <groupId>clj-http</groupId>
   <artifactId>clj-http</artifactId>
   <version>0.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: <repositoriry> tag should be wrapped with <repositories> tag and then solution works great :)

Comment: The accepted answer is more to the point of just downloading the JAR. This answer presumes the existence of a POM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Leiningen you can just read all about how to connect to repository server on a [recent Sonatype blog post](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2012/04/are-you-using-a-leiningen-repository-manager/) from Tim O'Brien.

If you are using Maven you should get a repo server like Nexus and setup the clojure repo as another proxy repository and add it to your public group.

If neither of these approaches is ok with you you can use Raghurams approach or number23_cn. Both of them however are semi optimal and will not scale for teams or many artifacts..