# including jars in clojure

Tags: java, jar, clojure, classpath

I have downloaded and installed a jar with Maven (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808898/install-jar-from-remote-repo-clojar)) but now I need to require it inside of a project. I followed the instructions on the [git README](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http) (`(require '[clj-http.client :as client])`) but I still get this error:

```
FileNotFoundException Could not locate clj_http/client__init.class or clj_http/client.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:430)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers on this thread will certainly work .... But adding jars directly on your machine's CLASSPATH or at the command line can be a very difficult strategy for development . . .

**The most common, idiomatic way to include jars in a clojure app is [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) (easy, one step install on github -- begginers should check note at the end of this answer for a caveat)...  Leiningen can also install the clojure environment and launch your repl for you, preloaded with the right jar environment.**

It  is essentially a java dependency manager and build tool rolled into one - i.e. like ivy or the maven Pom.xml which we use for java development.

**A Few examples of how to use Leiningen to interact with multiple libs in a simple and scalable fashion :**

To launch a repl, such that the jars in your project.clj file are on the classpath :

```
lein repl
```

To update your jars in your maven repo specified by your project.clj :

```
lein deps
```

Finally , lein let's you export "uberjars" which are akin to "fatjars", i.e. they have all the dependencies bundled for you.

**A minor update regarding the new Lein version : Note for begginers.**

There are two scripts you can run to install Leiningan, it might be safer to run this one:

https://github.com/jayunit100/leiningen/blob/stable/bin/lein (the **stable** release)

Rather than this one:

https://raw.github.com/technomancy/leiningen/preview/bin/lein (the **latest update**, which is a preview).

Comment: This is more of a content change than I'm willing to make to someone else's post without discussion -- but IMHO, the bolding really does a lot to reduce readability here. Getting rid of the first paragraph and debolding the second one would probably make for a cleaner answer.

Answer (score 5):

when you start the java process you need to do:

```
java -cp ./lib/clj-http.jar ./lib/clojure.jar clojure.main
```

Basically you need both clojure.jar (which is where the REPL is at) AND clj-http.jar in the classpath.

Assuming clj-http.jar is in ./lib/ directory. Or you could build your project with lein (build tool, similar to maven) and have it build an uberjar, which is what I would do. There's a pretty good walkthrough of setting up lein and building an uberjar here: http://zef.me/2470/building-clojure-projects-with-leiningen.

Comment: So I have to build an uberjar whenever I add dependencies? I created a folder at ~/.clojure where I will just dump all of my jars. I tried `java -cp ~/.clojure/clj-http-0.4.1.jar clojure.main` but no luck. It doesn't like the last part

Comment: Chris: my clojure bash script for you ref: https://github.com/number23/iLibrary/blob/master/clojure/clojure

Comment: So I have to add things to the class path every time I want to run the REPL? That sounds... less than ideal

Comment: I *think* if you use lein, and run `lein repl` it will run the repl with any dependencies set in your project.clj file. Or you could write your own launcher script that adds anything in `./lib` to the classpath of the started java process. But ultimately it's just java. So yes, you do need to set dependencies in the classpath somehow.

Comment: Another option is setting the CLASSPATH environment variable, but again you'd need to do this each time you opened a new shell.

Comment: But if this were in my bash profile (and I remember to add everything to a ~/.clojure folder) then everything would just always be there?

Comment: sure, you could set up a bash_profile to do stuff like that automatically. Assuming you always want the same jars on the classpath each time you start the repl.

Comment: Is there a reason to not have everything available?

Comment: @Kevin you're correct, leiningen will automate setting up the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

add clj-http.jar to CLASSPATH or CP before you start clojure repl.

Comment: I looked up `add-classpath` and it has been deprecated. How would I add the jar to the class path?